# how can I adjust a pic's length and width when i plot using r

Tags: r

I am trying to put 3 pics in a line into one pic, but it seems that the final one is square and it makes every pic looking squeezed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1<-qplot(Boston$crim, binwidth=5 , xlab = "Crime rate", 
ylab="Number of Suburbs" )
p2<-qplot(Boston$tax, binwidth=50 , xlab = "Full-value property-tax 
rate per $10,000", ylab="Number of Suburbs")
p3<-qplot(Boston$ptratio, binwidth=5, xlab ="Pupil-teacher ratio by 
town", ylab="Number of Suburbs")
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,ncol=3)
```

Here is what I got:

blob:https://stackoverflow.com/9102bbec-5108-4558-a320-e25014de5e4d

I wonder if there is any way to put them in a pic under the promise that images are not squeezed.

Comment: blob:https://stackoverflow.com/9102bbec-5108-4558-a320-e25014de5e4d

Comment: Link to your image is broken.

Comment: Are you using `data("Boston", package="MASS")`?

Comment: It's not clear if what you're saying is wrong is due to the data (your `p3`?) or because you want to change the relative widths of the images. If you read `?grid.arrange`, one of the arguments is `widths=`, so if you do (say) `grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,ncol=3,widths=c(1,1,3))`, you change the look. If this isn't it, you should fix the link to your image and be clear about what is wrong about it.

Comment: thanks, that is helpful.@r2evans

Comment: sorry, i've tried and it doesn't work.@neilfws